# Отправка формы по api записать в JSON Angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs, form

У меня имеется api конкретного JSON файла в который я должен записать:
1. Имя пользователя
2. Его коммент
3. Страницу, с которой был отправлен коммент

Что я имею:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">                 
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя">
  </div>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Ваш комментарий">
      </textarea>
  <div class="form-group text-right">
      <button type="submit" class="SendFormBtn">Отправить</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Эта страница конролится контроллером (ссори) "DetailCtrl" который получает товар под определенным ID, что в принципе тоже нужно отправить в JSON, поскольку он-то формирует адрес страницы. 
DetailCtrl:

```
velesApp.controller('DetailCtrl',['$scope','$http', '$location', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {
  $scope.kitchenId = $routeParams.kitchenId;
  var url = '/api/v1/kitchens/'+$routeParams.kitchenId; 
  $http.get(url).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  $scope.kitchen = data;  
  });
  $http.get('/api/v1/kitchens').success(function(data, status, headers,    config) {$scope.kitchens = data;});
  $http.get('/api/v1/hits').success(function(data, status, headers, config) { $scope.offerdets = data; });
  }]);
```

Вот ссылка на JSON 
(post) /api/v1/commentaries.json

Подскажите, как использовать метот POST, я с ангуляром знаком 1.5 недели.
З.Ы. мог бы попробовать прописать ng-model полям, но боюсь что я их еще неправильно понимаю

Comment: никак, ангуляр это клиентская технология, чтобы записать изменить файл на сервере, нужна серверная технология. Что вы используете на сервере? добавьте больше подробностей

Comment: @Grundy, здравствуйте снова, очень вам рад!  дело в том что у нас rest архитектура, я знаю что там бекенд на руби (рельсы). У меня есть только apiшка, куда нужно записать эти данные.

Comment: Добавьте этот апи - фактически адрес на который вы должны что-то послать, и какой формат он принимает, и еще можно пример контроллера _DetailCtrl_

Comment: velesApp.controller('DetailCtrl',['$scope','$http', '$location', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {
   $scope.kitchenId = $routeParams.kitchenId;
   var url = '/api/v1/kitchens/'+$routeParams.kitchenId; 
  $http.get(url).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.kitchen = data;  
  });
  $http.get('/api/v1/kitchens').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.kitchens = data;  
  });
  $http.get('/api/v1/hits').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.offerdets = data;  
  }); }]);

Comment: в сам вопрос это добавьте

Comment: @ Grundy , Я изменил вопрос

Comment: _/api/v1/commentaries.json_ - этот адрес и для get и для post?

Comment: @Grundy для POST

Comment: в принципе может по аналогии с _$http.get_ использовать _$http.post_, и передавать вторым параметром данные которые нужно послать

Comment: @Grundy , Я попробовал так же, только я не понимаю как данные из ng-modal попадают в $scope. Но если я иду в правильном направлении, то буду читать про это, спасибо !)

Comment: смотря как вы их прописываете во view, добавьте пример как вы их прописывали

Comment: немного позже смогу

Comment: забыли обновить? :-)